# Why do people choose to put all inline methods into another file?

Tags: c++

I saw some libraries put all inline methods into another separate file? Is there any benefit about this practice?

for example, put all inline methods into test.hin and include test.hin in the header file?

Answer (score 4):

To make the header easier to read.

Ideally anyone else looking at the file will get all the information they need just from the class/function declarations, appropriate names, and accompanying comments and documentation. The actual implementation of the inlined functions shouldn't be needed to be seen (most of the time). So rather than having all the extra stuff which people would have to skip past, one can choose to move it out into a separate "inlines" file.

As far as the compiler is concerned, it ends up working the same as if they were in the main header.

Comment: You can also do a halfway approach and put the definitions at the front of the header and the implementations at the end of the same file, with some blank lines or other decoration to separate them.